# Can I setup my .emacs file to auto-indent my source file when I open the file?

Tags: emacs

I want to be able to open a .java or .c file and have it automatically indent every line to the correct spacing. What line(s) can I add to my .emacs file to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I certainly wouldn't want to do that — it's a little bit too automated for my taste.  But if you're really sure, the following should do the trick:

```
(defun jdn-indent-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (indent-region (point-min) (point-max)))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'jdn-indent-buffer)
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook #'jdn-indent-buffer)
```